# Out of memory issue with celery and redis - need help tuning celery

Tags: django, redis, out-of-memory, celery, celery-task

I have a django 2 app that uploads 1 to many photographs (~3-4 MB per image), and uses face_recognition to find the face locations and encoding. The images and created thumbnails are saved to the file system and the data in a mysql database. The app works, except that uploading and finding 16 faces in 3 photos takes about 2 min and uses about 6.5 GB of RAM and no swap (my Ubuntu 18.04 system has a total of 16 GB of RAM and runs with about 8 GB of free memory and 1 GB of swap.)

When I use celery (v 4.2.1) and redis (v 2.10.6) and redis-server (v 4.0.9) to offload the face recognition from my django app, the celery tasks run out of memory and the workers are killed before they finish There is 1 celery task per photo for face recognition and django handles the file uploading, thumbnail creation and db writingfor the three photos. Usually 1 task will finish, but not always. I even added exponential retries for the celery tasks, but that did not help. Looking at top during the celery face recognition, I noticed that the amount of free RAM stayed around 6 GB, but the 1 GB of swap is totally consumed and then the celery tasks start to die. The error message I get is out of memory when they die.

From my observations, I conclude that my system has enough RAM for these three pictures, but somehow I need to tune celery so that it uses less swap and more memory. I am not sure if this is the real problem or not, nor have I found any way to tune celery. BTW, I have the same issues whether I run django in debug mode or not.

Thanks for any suggestions you may have to solve this problem of celery running out of memory.

Mark

Comment: Hi, if you still haven't found a solution, consider asking this on [celery-users](http://groups.google.com/group/celery-users/) mailing list.

Comment: Thanks! I also posted there, but still no response. I have been experimenting with various process and thread pools and still have issues. I will create a new post with those specific questions.